# Cannot send data to firebase collection

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to send data on firebase collection but I can't figure out why it can't be sent. Function called `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` works normally. In other functions sending data in firebase collection is working fine when I want to send it, but here it doesn't work for some unknown reason. Is this some bug or what?

My function:

```
SignUp() {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password);
  try {
    
    const unique = this.email;
    db.collection("user")
      .doc(unique)
      .set({
        name: this.name,
        surname: this.surname,
        email: this.email,
        birth_date: this.birth_date,
        city: this.city,
        phone_number: this.phone_number,
      });
    this.success_register=true;
  }
   catch(error) {
      if ((store.currentUser = null)) this.$router.replace({ name: "signup" });
    }
  
}
```

Comment: The `SignUp` function just seems to create user in Firebase Auth and the Firestore code seems to be out of it's scope. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: @Dharmaraj thanks for the correction, the function was not well copied, now I have corrected how it really looks.

Comment: There is no curly bracket closing the try block

Comment: Both the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` and `set()` method return a promise. Can you try using an async function as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/a500ac45bffa8faeb1940377d234b392)?